# WP8 Listbox takes too much time to render UI for large set of items

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8, listbox, observablecollection

I have a large `ObservableCollection` containing text data which is populated to a listbox itemssource. Data fetching is fine, but Listbox rendering takes time, about 4-5 seconds. 
Plus, I have a textbox where I want to filter out the listbox itemesource, if the text entered   in the textbox starts with the item's text using Linq.

```
List<Locality> l = Collection.FindAll(Locality=>Locality.name.ToLower().StartsWith(keywordlocation.Text.Trim()));
```

The filtering also takes time in the data set and is ruining user experience. Any ideas how to decrease the rendering time and improve filtering.

Comment: how is your ListBox defined? do you use virtualization on the ListBox?

Comment: How large is the collection? What is the data structure? Is there any DataTemplate used by the Lisbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Missed on a few details. `VirtualizationStackpanel` mode set to `Recycling` helped in rendering data faster and filtering out content.